# Hide header texts (Title & Tagline) in custom-header.php

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, custom-header

I am currently trying to enhance my theme development skills and still have a lot to learn in php.

I'm investigating the code  of [`Underscores`](http://underscores.me) and `Twenty Seventeen` themes.
I simply do not understand why the following code works and what it does to hide `Site Title` and `Tagline`, if the `Display Site Title and Tagline` checkbox in Customizer is unchecked.

In `custom-header.php`, after setting up the custom header with a default text color of `#000000`, themes set up a function for header style:

```
function underscores_header_style() {
    $header_text_color = get_header_textcolor();

    /*
     * If no custom options for text are set, let's bail.
     * get_header_textcolor() options: Any hex value, 'blank' to hide text. Default: add_theme_support( 'custom-header' ).
     */
    if ( get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' ) === $header_text_color ) {
        return;
    }

    // If we get this far, we have custom styles. Let's do this.
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
```

If I now set the color of Header Text to `#000000` in Customizer, in my opinion, the first `if` clause should become true, the `return;` should end the function and the whole following styling part for hiding and beyond shouldn't be working.

So far I've checked with `var_dump()` for `get_header_textcolor()` and `get_theme_support('custom-header', 'default-text-color')`. Both the values are `000000`.

In contrast to my above considerations: Everything works correctly.

I don't want to just "copy – paste" this issue in my theme, I want to understand it. Where is my thinking error?

Comment: A bit related, you can use `$wp_customize->remove_control('header_textcolor');` to remove the color control that's added by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, When you uncheck `Display Site Title and Tagline` in the customizer, it doesn't matter what value you've already put in `Header Text Color`, the customizer saves it as `blank` (not empty string, the actual text "blank") after you `Save & Publish`. You may check this in `wp_options` table in the database after you `Save & Publish` ***or*** try `var_dump()` after moving out of the customizer.

Since `get_header_textcolor()` returns `blank` and `get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' )` returns `000000`, they don't match in the above mentioned `if` condition, so the hiding works.

Secondly, you get `000000` with `var_dump()` for both `get_header_textcolor()` and `get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' )` when you are in the customizer, because customizer doesn't reload the page after saving & it uses JavaScript to show / hide `Title` & `Tagline` before saving. If you close the customizer after saving, you'll see that `var_dump()` will show `blank` for `get_header_textcolor()` and `000000` for `get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-text-color' )`.

This is the line the customizer uses to save the value as `blank` in the [`wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js#L5264) file:

```
    control.setting.set( to ? last : 'blank' );
```

Also, in [`wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L4197) file's `_sanitize_header_textcolor` function, you'll see that WordPress allows `blank` to be a valid input for `header_textcolor` along with any valid color value in hex format:

```
    if ( 'blank' === $color )
        return 'blank';
```

So your logic was correct, but you got the value wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now is everything chrystal clear for me. Your answer saved me a lot of further headaches. The "blank" issue was the point. I marked this answer as useful too, it will be shown if my reputation become larger than 15... .